# For loop to replace value in one dataframe with X if it appears in another dataframe

Tags: python

Wondering if someone could shed some light on a for loop to perform the following.

**df1**

```
col1:
A
B
C
D
E
```

**df2**

```
col2:
A
C
D
```

If the value in df2 appear in df1, replace with X, else replace with Y and append a new column.

**Final df1**

```
col3:
X
Y
X
X
Y
```

Comment: Using a `for` loop with a pandas dataframe is almost never a good idea. In this case, you can solve the problem with `np.where` but it might be good to practice yourself writing the for loop. Note that if you are stuck writing the for loop or get the wrong results, you can post your attempt here. The StackOverflow community is much more receptive to questions where there is effort shown in finding your own solution.

Comment: Why a `for` loop? What did you try in pandas? Add your [example] and please also add specific tags, e.g. [tag:pandas].

Answer (score 4):

As [Kraigolas commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713383/for-loop-to-replace-value-in-one-dataframe-with-x-if-it-appears-in-another-dataf#comment125009505_70713383), you can easily do this without looping.

Check if elements are in another array with [`np.in1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and then map truth values to "X" and "Y":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1["col1"] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["col2"] = ["A", "C", "D"]

df1["col3"] = list(map(lambda x: "X" if x else "Y", np.in1d(df1.col1, df2.col2)))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col3
0    A    X
1    B    Y
2    C    X
3    D    X
4    E    Y
```

Comment: To better __express the sequence of steps__ we could either separate statements in numpy `step1 = np.in1d(..); step2 = map(..)` or benefit from [__chaining in pandas__](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-unreasonable-effectiveness-of-method-chaining-in-pandas-15c2109e3c69?gi=cf0b14dc80de):  `result = pandas.Series.in1d(..).map(..)` using pandas' [`map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Answer (score 1):

Given question with `dataframe` in title, variables `df1` and `df2` together with `col1` and `col2` probably is related to [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) or [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy).

Without any further context provided, like code, we can only recommend vague options but not help with a specific solution.

### Functions from Numpy, Pandas and Python built-in

Following are some functions in the solution space:

1. element is in other collection: `numpy.in1d` (explained below), [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), [`set & other` or `set.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set%20intersection#frozenset.intersection)
2. map boolean to string or character: `numpy.where` (explained below), [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=map%20function#map)

#### Value in 1-D array (exists / present / duplicated)

See numpy's [`in1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False, invert=False)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) function:

> Test whether each element of a 1-D array is also present in a second array.

```py
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(array_1)
# ['A' 'B' 'C']
array_1_elements_exist = np.in1d(array_1, ['C', 'D'])
print(array_1_elements_exist)
# [False False  True]
```

#### Map to either X or Y (binary classification)

The mapping can be done using Python's built-in [`map(mapping_function, array_or_list)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) as [answered by rikyeah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70714258/5730279).

Or directly use numpy's [`where(condition, [x, y, ])`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

> Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition.

to map binary values (in statistics this is called [*binary classification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification#Binary_and_multiclass_classification)):

```py
import numpy as np

array_bool = np.array([True, False])
print(array_bool)
# array([ True, False])
array_str = np.where(array_bool, 'x', 'y')
print(array_bool)
# array(['x', 'y'], dtype='|S1')
```

### Comparing two dataframes? (missing context for specific application)

As the question hasn't shown a reproducible example yet, it is unclear how the combined functionality can be applied in context.

Until some [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is provided in given question, the combination of both functions is left open.

Example applications of these functions to *pandas* are:

- [python: check if an numpy array contains any element of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190533/python-check-if-an-numpy-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array/36190611#36190611)
- [Difference between pandas DataFrame 'where' and Numpy 'where'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893381/difference-between-pandas-dataframe-where-and-numpy-where)
- [comparing two DataFrames, specific questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273037/comparing-two-dataframes-specific-questions)

Or in built-in Python:

- Python docs [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set%20intersection#frozenset.intersection)
- [using a conditional and lambda in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153002/using-a-conditional-and-lambda-in-map)